# What are the ICAO fuel reserve requirements?

Tags: flight-planning, fuel, icao-sarps

How much reserve fuel are private and commercial aircraft required to carry by ICAO rules?

I heard that it changed recently (about a year ago) and is a little complicated.  How is it calculated for a particular flight?

Comment: It's no longer 'enough to get to your destination plus 30 minutes'?

Comment: @flyingfisch one source I looked at also required you to get to your alt and then make a missed approach + 30 minutes

Comment: @ratchetfreak ah ok, the ground school course I took a couple years ago said enough to get to the destination, plus 30 minutes. Of course, things may have changed, and/or the ground school course simplified the rules.

Comment: @flyingfisch and different rules if the nearest diversion field is more than 30 minutes plus circle time away, and at night, and and and...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The following includes the changes you allude to (which were proposed in [ICAO State Letter SP 59/4.1-11/8](http://caa.bg/upload/docs/ANNEX_6_EDTO.pdf) on June 30, 2011).

### Commercial Flights

Per ICAO Annex 6, Part I, section 4.3.6 "Fuel Requirements," airplanes should calculate their required fuel quantity as follows (summary; see below for actual ICAO text):

- Taxi fuel
- Trip fuel (to reach intended destination)
- Contingency fuel (higher of 5% of "trip fuel" or 5 minutes of holding flight)
- Destination alternate fuel (to fly a missed and reach an alternate)
- Final reserve fuel (45 minutes of holding flight for reciprocating engines, 30 minutes for jets)
- Additional fuel (if needed to guarantee ability to reach an alternate with an engine failure or at lower altitude due to a pressurization loss)
- Discretionary fuel (if the pilot in command wants it)

### General Aviation

For general aviation, ICAO Annex 6 Part II, section 2.2.3.6 "Fuel and oil supply" requires:

- For IFR, enough fuel to reach destination, then alternate (if required), plus 45 minutes
- For day VFR, enough fuel to reach destination plus 30 minutes
- For night VFR, enough fuel to reach destination plus 45 minutes

### ICAO Annex 6 Part I

From the [ninth edition](http://www.bazl.admin.ch/experten/regulation/03080/03081/index.html):

> **4.3.6.3** The pre-flight calculation of usable fuel required shall include:
>
> a) *taxi fuel*, which shall be the amount of fuel expected to be consumed before take-off;
>
> b) *trip fuel*, which shall be the amount of fuel required to enable the aeroplane to fly from take-off, or the point of in-flight
>   re-planning, until landing at the destination aerodrome taking into account the operating conditions of 4.3.6.2 b);
>
> c) *contingency fuel*, which shall be the amount of fuel required to compensate for unforeseen factors. It shall be five per
>   cent of the planned trip fuel or of the fuel required from the point of in-flight re-planning based on the consumption
>   rate used to plan the trip fuel but, in any case, shall not be lower than the amount required to fly for five minutes at
>   holding speed at 450 m (1 500 ft) above the destination aerodrome in standard conditions;
>
> > *Note.— Unforeseen factors are those which could have an influence on the fuel consumption to the destination
> >     aerodrome, such as deviations of an individual aeroplane from the expected fuel consumption data, deviations from
> >     forecast meteorological conditions, extended taxi times before take-off, and deviations from planned routings and/or
> >     cruising levels.*
>
> d) *destination alternate fuel*, which shall be:
>
> 1. where a destination alternate aerodrome is required, the amount of fuel required to enable the aeroplane to:
>      i) perform a missed approach at the destination aerodrome;
>      ii) climb to the expected cruising altitude;
>      iii) fly the expected routing;
>      iv) descend to the point where the expected approach is initiated; and
>      v) conduct the approach and landing at the destination alternate aerodrome; or
> 2. where two destination alternate aerodromes are required, the amount of fuel, as calculated in 4.3.6.3 d) 1),
>      required to enable the aeroplane to proceed to the destination alternate aerodrome which requires the greater
>      amount of alternate fuel; or
> 3. where a flight is operated without a destination alternate aerodrome, the amount of fuel required to enable the
>      aeroplane to fly for 15 minutes at holding speed at 450 m (1 500 ft) above destination aerodrome elevation in
>      standard conditions; or
> 4. where the aerodrome of intended landing is an isolated aerodrome:
>      i) for a reciprocating engine aeroplane, the amount of fuel required to fly for 45 minutes plus 15 per cent of the
>      flight time planned to be spent at cruising level, including final reserve fuel, or two hours, whichever is less;
>      or
>      ii) for a turbine-engined aeroplane, the amount of fuel required to fly for two hours at normal cruise
>      consumption above the destination aerodrome, including final reserve fuel;
>
> e) *final reserve fuel*, which shall be the amount of fuel calculated using the estimated mass on arrival at the destination
>   alternate aerodrome, or the destination aerodrome when no destination alternate aerodrome is required:
>
> 1. for a reciprocating engine aeroplane, the amount of fuel required to fly for 45 minutes, under speed and altitude
>      conditions specified by the State of the Operator; or
> 2. for a turbine-engined aeroplane, the amount of fuel required to fly for 30 minutes at holding speed at 450 m
>      (1 500 ft) above aerodrome elevation in standard conditions;
>
> f) *additional fuel*, which shall be the supplementary amount of fuel required if the minimum fuel calculated in accordance with 4.3.6.3 b), c), d) and e) is not sufficient to:
>
> 1. allow the aeroplane to descend as necessary and proceed to an alternate aerodrome in the event of engine failure
>      or loss of pressurization, whichever requires the greater amount of fuel based on the assumption that such a failure
>      occurs at the most critical point along the route;
>      i) fly for 15 minutes at holding speed at 450 m (1 500 ft) above aerodrome elevation in standard conditions; and
>      ii) make an approach and landing;
> 2. allow an aeroplane engaged in EDTO to comply with the EDTO critical fuel scenario as established by the State
>      of the Operator;
> 3. meet additional requirements not covered above;
>
> > *Note 1.— Fuel planning for a failure that occurs at the most critical point along a route (4.3.6.3 f) 1)) may place
> >     the aeroplane in a fuel emergency situation based on 4.3.7.2.*
> >
> > *Note 2.— Guidance on EDTO critical fuel scenarios is contained in Attachment D;*
>
> g) *discretionary fuel*, which shall be the extra amount of fuel to be carried at the discretion of the pilot-in-command.

### ICAO Annex 6 Part II

> **2.2.3.6** Fuel and oil supply
>
> A flight shall not be commenced unless, taking into account both the meteorological conditions and any delays that are
>   expected in flight, the aeroplane carries sufficient fuel and oil to ensure that it can safely complete the flight. The amount of
>   fuel to be carried must permit:
>
> a) when the flight is conducted in accordance with the instrument flight rules and a destination alternate aerodrome is
>   not required in accordance with 2.2.3.5, flight to the aerodrome of intended landing, and after that, for at least 45
>   minutes at normal cruising altitude; or
>
> b) when the flight is conducted in accordance with the instrument flight rules and a destination alternate aerodrome is
>   required, flight from the aerodrome of intended landing to an alternate aerodrome, and after that, for at least 45
>   minutes at normal cruising altitude; or
>
> c) when the flight is conducted in accordance with the visual flight rules by day, flight to the aerodrome of intended
>   landing, and after that, for at least 30 minutes at normal cruising altitude; or
>
> d) when the flight is conducted in accordance with the visual flight rules by night, flight to the aerodrome of intended
>   landing and thereafter for at least 45 minutes at normal cruising altitude.

Answer (score 0):

Fuel & oil (propeller –driven A/c)

A) When a destination alternate is required

B) When destination aerodrome is VMC /alternate not required

C) When a destination is isolated and no suitable destination alternate is available

i. Fuel to destination ………. A
(includes one approach and a missed approach)

ii. + fuel is specified diversion ……….B

iii. + 45 mts
i.e A+B+45 mts

i. Fuel to destination …. A

ii. +45 mts
i.e A+45 mts

i. Fuel to destination …. A

ii. + 45 mts+15 5 of cruising time or 2 hrs ….B

which is less

i.e A+B

Fuel & oil (Turbo jets)

A. When a destination alternate is required

Fuel destination including an approach and a missed approach ...A

Fuel to alternate aerodrome as specified in flights plan …B

- 30 mts holding at 1500’ at holding speed above alternate aerodrome in ISA
- Approach
- land

Additional contingency fuel as specified by operator …C

i.e A+B + 30 mts holding at 1500’ +approach + landing fuel +C

B. When a destination alternate is not required because destination is VMC

Fuel to destination + 30 mts holding fuel at 1500’ above the aerodrome destination at holding speed in ISA …. B

Additional contingency fuel as specified by operator …C

i.e A+B+C

C. When destination is isolated and no suitable destination alternate aerodrome is available

Fuel to destination + 2 hrs fuel at normal fuel cruise consumption …. B

i.e A+B

Comment: I cannot figure out how to properly edit this for decent spacing