# Is it normal practice to refuel commerical planes whilst boarding is taking place?

Tags: commercial-aviation, refueling, boarding

The other day, I was on a KLM Boeing 737. I had just sat down in my seat, and the captain was making announcement. He said something along the lines of,

> As we are refuelling at this moment, please take your seat quickly, leaving your seat belt open, and follow any instructions by the cabin crew immediately

This suggests to me that refuelling whilst boarding is not normal, as I've never heard this before, and it sounds like they want us to be ready to evacuate if something goes wrong with the refuelling.

Comment: Related: [Under what conditions are passengers required to take precautionary measures during refueling?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7629)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Refueling with passengers onboard is quite normal and is done according to the recommendations of regulatory bodies/manufacturers and operators. Refueling with some fuel types are not permitted, while others are. From [Airbus Flight Operations Briefing notes](http://www.airbus.com/fileadmin/media_gallery/files/safety_library_items/AirbusSafetyLib_-FLT_OPS-GND_HAND-SEQ01.pdf):

> Refueling  with  wide  cut  gasoline  type  fuel (JET  B,  JP4  or  equivalent)  or  when  a  mixture  with  these  types  of  fuel  might  occur,  is  not  permitted  with  passengers  boarding, on board or disembarking.
>
> Refueling with Kerosene (JET A, JET A1 JP8, TS1, RT, TH or equivalent, as approved by  the  approved  Aircraft  Flight  Manual),  is  allowed  when  passengers  are  boarding,  on board, or disembarking.

Some precautions are required to be followed in case refueling is done with passengers on board. The announcement you heard is simply following that. From [Appendix 1 to JAR-OPS 1.305 Refuelling/defuelling with passengers
embarking, on board or disembarking](http://www.caa.md/files/2014_01/567.pdf):

> (a)   An  operator  must  establish  operational procedures   for   e/defuelling   with   passengers embarking,  on  board  or  disembarking  o  ensure  the following precautions are taken:
>
> (1)   One qualified person must remain at a specified location during fuelling operations with passengers  n  board.  This  qualified  person  must be  capable  of  handling  emergency  procedures concerning  fire  protection  and  fire-fighting, handling  communications  and  initiating  and directing an evacuation;
>
> (2) A  two-way  communication  shall  be established  and  shall  remain  available  by  the aeroplane’s  inter-communication  system  or  other suitable   means   between   the   ground   crew supervising  the  refuelling  and  the  qualified personnel on board the aeroplane;
>
> (3)  Crew,  staff  and  passengers  must  be warned that re/defuelling will take place;
>
> (4)  Fasten eat Belts’ signs must be off;
>
> (5)  ‘NO  SMOKING’  signs  must  be  on, together   with   interior   lighting   to   enable emergency exits to be identified;
>
> (6)  Passengers  must  be  instructed  to unfasten  their  seat  belts  and  refrain  from smoking;
>
> (7)  Sufficient qualified personnel must e on  board  and  be  prepared  for  an  immediate emergency evacuation;
>
> (8)  If  the  presence  of  fuel  vapour  is detected inside the aeroplane, or any other hazard arises  during  re/defuelling,  fuelling  must  be stopped immediately;
>
> (9)  The  ground  area  beneath  the  exits intended  or  emergency  evacuation  and  slide deployment areas must be kept clear; and
>
> (10) Provision is made for a safe and rapid evacuation.

You're right about the announcement and leaving seat belt open- it is to help in quick evacuation. The flight crew is just following the procedure.

Comment: Some airlines also require passengers to keep their shoes on.

Comment: It's very common on Ryanair flights. Any time the plane spends on the ground is a cost, and anything that reduces this will reduce the airlines costs.

Answer (score 7):

Typical terminal operations prefer fueling to start once passengers are off the plane, and to be finished before the boarding of the new passengers.

However if time constraints forced your situation, there are procedures to follow:

---

### The ramp agent must ensure that:

- The flight crew, cabin crew and engineer are at their stations
- The area beneath exits intended for emergency evacuation is kept clear
- **The fire service is alerted**
- Passenger boarding / disembarkation is achieved in a controlled manner.

### The flight crew must:

- Establish communication with the ground engineer
- Inform the cabin crew of the beginning and ending of refueling
- Listen for fire warning from the engineer
- Be prepared to initiate passenger evacuation if necessary.

### The ground engineer must:

- Establish communications with the flight crew
- Inform the flight crew of the beginning and ending of refueling
- Notify flight crew, if a fire occurs
- If an emergency evacuation is required, indicate (to the flight crew) the exits that are clear of obstruction. The flight crew must then inform the cabin crew
- Stop refueling upon flight crew request.

### The cabin crew must:

- Establish communication with the flight crew
- Inform passengers not to smoke (the "NO SMOKING" sign must be on)
- Inform passengers to **unfasten their seat belts**
  (THE "FASTEN SEAT BELT" sign must be off)
- Ensure that emergency exits remain clear of obstruction
- Ensure that the "EXIT" sign is on
- Ensure that ground servicing (e.g. catering or cleaning) cannot create a hazard, or delay an emergency evacuation.

Souce: [Refueling with Passengers On Board](http://www.airbus.com/fileadmin/media_gallery/files/safety_library_items/AirbusSafetyLib_-FLT_OPS-GND_HAND-SEQ01.pdf)

Comment: For clarity, the NO SMOKING and FASTEN SEAT BELTS signs are controlled by the flight crew. The cabin crew enforces it.

Comment: ...there are times when the NO SMOKING signs _aren't_ on?

Comment: @Sean Depends on the country. In most countries nowadays, no, there is no time where smoking is allowed. Indeed, many newer aircraft cabin interiors have replaced the no smoking lighted signs with fixed placards.