# Is it economically profitable for airports use jetties that use all the airbus A380's 16 exits at the same time

Tags: airport, airbus-a380

Does it make economic sense or is it economically profitable for airports to build jetties or jetty facilities that use all the airbus A380's 16 exits at the same time.  This would be very convinient for passengers with less time waiting in a que to embark and disembark the aircraft and would be beneficial to airliners because they'd spend less time waiting for passengers to disembark the aircraft, cleaning crews entering the plane quicker getting it ready for a new set of passengers sooner who would enter the plane quicker.  They'd also pay less for parking space at airports as they'd spend less time there.  The airports would free up their parking spaces quicker and would service more planes per day and get more revenue. Win... Win... Win!!!

Comment: As we've discussed [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/50058/14897) and [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/50056/14897), the biggest constraints are the refueling and the adjacent gates. I recommend finding a solution to those problems first, before proposing a new idea. In its current state, you'll just get a repeat of the other answers.

Comment: See also [How long does it take to refuel a big jumbo jet?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26132/52).  Since passenger loading isn't critical path, making it quicker won't change the time the plane spends at the gate.

Comment: Since Airbus has discontinued the A380, it would make very little economical sense at this point to begin the redesign process for an aircraft whose numbers will only decrease over time.