# Is there a light civilian helicopter capable of a 250 NM trip without refueling?

Tags: general-aviation, helicopter

Is there any light civilian (GA) helicopter that's capable of making a 250 NM trip with [required fuel reserves](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3740/62)? I'm thinking of something smaller and lighter that a private individual might buy. (I'm thinking about something that costs less than USD 150K, if that helps to explain the type/size of helicopter I'm asking about.)

The [Robinson R22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_R22) and [RotorWay A600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RotorWay_A600_Talon) look like they wouldn't make it without a refueling stop, and I haven't found any extended range [STCs](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/design_approvals/stc/) for these either.

Does anyone know if such a helicopter exists?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't believe we entertain shopping recommendations on Aviation.SE any more than we do on any other Stack...

Comment: Helicopter under $150k? Maybe one that is close to timing out... Be aware that the very expensive parts (like gear boxes) on heli's have a limited lifespan. For example, the R-22 requires a very expensive [major overhaul at 2200 hours or 12 years](http://www.robinsonheli.com/manuals/r22_mm/r22_mm_3.pdf) involving rotor systems, drive system, control system, and fuselage.

Comment: Fail to see how "is there a G.A. helicoptor out there with 250NM range" is off topic.  The O.P. mentions his motivation for asking, but the question is either on-topic or not, irrespective of the motivation behind it.

Comment: @RalphJ Help center cites the following as off topic: `Resource location: Where to buy a specific part, "Which headset is the best?", etc.` This question sounds very much like a resource location question which would fit well elsewhere but not here.

Comment: This question is neither "where to buy" nor asking for opinions on "best". The 250NM range question is purely factual, and entirely on-topic.

Comment: @RalphJ yes, but the "under $150k" is not.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a cessna 152 and a cheap airport car at your destination.

Comment: @acpilot Yeah, that's option #2 :) Though, having a heli as a time-builder would be pretty awesome and just so happens that I have family at 250nm in ether direction...

Comment: Thanks to those who edited the question rather than just closing it! I really appreciate it

Comment: Given the means I'd likely go for the heli.  You only live once so why not do it right??!!

Comment: It would seem your budget and desired range are at odds with each other. Someone linked this on another question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ultralight_helicopters - There are several in that list that start at $140k-150k, but range is usually < 200nm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would need a definition of the word 'light' as it is a little relative.  Most light turbine helicopters eg a [Bell 206 JetRanger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_206) or a [Hughes 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD_Helicopters_MD_500) will do this job just fine.

It is a little difficult to locate a reciprocating engine powered helo that meets those criteria.  The [Guimbal Cabri G2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guimbal_Cabri_G2) and the [Robinson R44](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_R44) would be my choices for that but cost over $300,000 a piece.

The [Schweizer (now Sikorsky) S333](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_S-333) would be another good choice.  It is a light turbine helicopter and [can be obtained for just shy of 200,000 USD](http://www.controller.com/listings/aircraft/for-sale/1451457/2006-schweizer-333), though you may be required to put another 100,000 USD or so into it.